# Can Ubuntu have any labview equivalent open source software?

Tags: open-source

Can Ubuntu have any `lab-view` equivalent open source software which is provide virtual electronics lab effects like lab-view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[OpenLab](http://www.myopenlab.de/) is quite a good option. It is German but you can choose English in the program.

- Extract the downloaded file and make the file `start_linux` executable with `chmod +x start_linux.sh`.
- Run it either by double-clicking the file or through the terminal `./start_linux.sh`.

**NOTE** OpenLab requires java, so make sure you have it installed.

Comment: Can you provide any working link for downloading. and installation process also. Edit your ans for more info.

Comment: But project is under-development....

Comment: I'm looking into it...

Comment: waw! and sorry for my wrong behavior about accepting and rejecting answer. I was confuse first after visit link.

Comment: @MadhavNikam No probs :) I've edited my answer to include another project.

Answer (score 0):

Try Parlay. We just open-sourced it - we use it internally for all of our projects.  It's a python based system with a browser UI for controlling and accessing embedded systems. http://promenadesoftware.com/parlay